# How to implement combo box and change values at run time in iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I have just started with iPhone development. I have to implement the following scenario:

I have to show 2 combo boxesin UITableView, one for department and other for employees which belong to that department.
If I select a particular department (say "Computers") all the employees belonging to that department should be loaded in the combo box of"employees".

Similarly if I change department the employees combo box should be reloaded every time with new employees for selected department.

Can I achieve this using iPhone app? Are there some links or documentation on how to do this?

Comment: Unortuately Stack Overflow doesn't allow bots. Otherwise I wrote one which changes any misspelling/miscapitalization of "iPhone" into the proper spelling/capitalization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIPickerview to give combo box functionality you can check the following tutorial.
[UIPickerViewExample](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/UIPickerView/UIPickerViewExample.html)